# Cannot create table with flyway (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, migration, database-migration, flyway

I try do create a simple mysql database with Flyway migration, but it doesn't going well.

I have created my .sql it named as V1_0__init.sql and I've written some sql commands there:

```
CREATE TABLE User (

    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    created DATE NOT NULL,
    username varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    status boolean NOT NULL,
    unique(username)

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I think it should be fine, but I have two errors, one at the first line (CREATE TABLE) and another at the fourth line (created DATE NOT NULL).

The error message says:
**Invalid or Incomplete statement
Expected one of the following: ALGORITHM DEFINER SQL VIEW**
(At the 'created DATE NOT NULL' line have a similar message, the only difference is this: Algoritm definer **OR** sql view)

I've tried to fix these but it didn't go well.
Anyone could help me how to fix this?

Maybe did I miss something? Should I do something in application.properties?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you use this primary key syntax?
```CREATE TABLE User (

    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    created DATE NOT NULL,
    username varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    status boolean NOT NULL,
    unique(username),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;```